# How to change the Plesk default theme?

Tags: centos, performance

We use Plesk 10.4 for our shared hosting server. How can I change the Plesk theme ?

```
branding_theme: command not found
```

Found here: http://download1.parallels.net/Plesk/PP10/10.1.1/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-administrator-guide/plesk-customizing-panel-appearance-branding-guide/

- System: centos5 (Linux)
- Plesk-Version: 10.4

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parallels Plesk Panel **does not provides a GUI powered theme manager** since Version 10.
You need to run the branding_theme Utility in the psa/bin directory to install new themes.

---

### **How to setup a new theme for all users:**

1. Enter the psa-directory

   ```
   # cd /usr/local/psa/bin/
   ```
2. Remove the current branding theme

   ```
   # ./branding_theme -u -vendor admin
   ```
3. Retrieve your new Theme for [**Parallels Plesk 10.4**](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/themes/)

   ```
   # wget http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/BrandingThemes/parallels_plesk_panel_10.4_light_theme.zip
   ```
4. Install the new theme

   ```
   # ./branding_theme -i -vendor admin -source parallels_plesk_panel_10.4_light_theme.zip
   ```

You can find more details about Panel Branding at the [**branding_theme Utility Guide**](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.2.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-unix-cli/index.htm?fileName=66508.htm).

---

### **How to setup a new theme for all users:**

Unfortunately, the [**branding_theme Utility**](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/10.2.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-unix-cli/index.htm?fileName=66508.htm) isn't able to set the default theme for all users at once.

You can use this workaround to replace the default theme with the new one

1. Enter the default skin directory

   ```
   # cd /usr/local/psa/var/branding/
   ```
2. Retrieve your new Theme for [**Parallels Plesk 10.4**](http://www.parallels.com/products/plesk/themes/)

   ```
   # wget http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP10/BrandingThemes/parallels_plesk_panel_10.4_light_theme.zip
   ```
3. Unpack the zipped theme file

   ```
   # unzip parallels_plesk_panel_10.4_light_theme.zip -d newtheme
   ```
4. Get the current hash for the installed default skin

   ```
   # find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d
   ```
5. You should get a result like this

   ```
   # ./info/d639d8b9-5382-462f-820e-e48e46efeb71
   # ./sb/skins
   # ./panel/skins
   ```
6. Use the hash and replace it with the commands below to flush the directory:

   ```
   # rm -Rf ./info/d639d8b9-5382-462f-820e-e48e46efeb71/* 
   # rm -Rf ./sb/skins/d639d8b9-5382-462f-820e-e48e46efeb71/* 
   # rm -Rf ./panel/skins/d639d8b9-5382-462f-820e-e48e46efeb71/*
   ```
7. Copy and Paste the new skin to the previous directory:

   ```
   # cp -r ./newtheme/info/ ./info/d639d8b9-5382-462f-820e-e48e46efeb71/
   # cp -r ./newtheme/panel/skins/* ./panel/skins/d639d8b9-5382-462f-820e-e48e46efeb71
   # cp -r ./newtheme/sb/skins/* ./sb/skins/d639d8b9-5382-462f-820e-e48e46efeb71
   ```
8. Clean up your branding directory:

   ```
   # rm -rf parallels_plesk_panel_10.4_light_theme.zip
   # rm -rf newtheme/
   ```

Enjoy!